# Get colorbar ticklabels

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have a scatter plot:

```
x,y,c,s = np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100)*100, np.random.rand(100)*100
plt.scatter(x,y,c=c,s=s,cmap='YlGnBu', alpha=0.3)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
```

How do I get the colorbar ticklabels? I can imagine that with `cbar.ax.get_yticklabels()` I get pretty close to the solution. However, given the figure below, I'd like to have something like:

```
array([ 10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,  50.,  60.,  70.,  80.,  90.])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the ticks on the scale of the y-axis of the colorbar, which has limits (0.0, 1.0)

```
cbar.ax.get_yticks()
```

This is what you need:

```
np.interp(cbar.ax.get_yticks(), cbar.ax.get_ylim(), cbar.get_clim())
```

The result is:

```
array([ 10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,  50.,  60.,  70.,  80.,  90.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x,y,c,s = np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100)*100, np.random.rand(100)*100
b = plt.scatter(x,y,c=c,s=s,cmap='YlGnBu', alpha=0.3)
cbar = plt.colorbar(b)
label_list = []
for i in cbar.ax.get_yticklabels():
    a = int(i.get_text())
    label_list.append(a)
print label_list
plt.show()
```

Comment: I got this list as answer [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

Comment: Wow. Thanks much. Guess my biggest problem was on reading the Text list.

Comment: cool, if you want float, you can use float() instead of int()